# Op Amp Voltage follower

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I built a simple non inverting op amp amplifier with 2 resistors and a TS972IN powered between 0-5V but my output was always set to 5V. I tried several others Op Amp, others resitors and I also moved my circuit elsewhere (I'm working with a breadboard) and none of this changed anything. In order to solve my issue, I decided to build something even simpler, a voltage follower but I have the same behavior, the output stays to 5V...

My circuit with the pinout I use:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV1stO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: that's an OPamp that's explicitly deprecated by its manufacturer; while certainly fine for learning and prototyping, be aware that it might not be possible to get any quantity of it in the future.

Comment: According to the datasheet https://pl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/ts971-957361.pdf, The allowed input voltage range lies between 1.35V...3.65V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data sheet, page 5:

> V<sub>icm</sub> Common mode input voltage range V<sub>DD</sub> + 1.15 to V<sub>CC</sub> - 1.15 V

You're trying to make it work V<sub>DD</sub> + 0 to V<sub>CC</sub> - 0 V; that won't do. This is just what is known as *Latch-up* behaviour.

You have a rail-to-rail **output** opamp. What you'd need to have is a rail-to-rail **input and output** (RRIO) opamp for this to work.

Comment: Many thanks I thought I was going insane, I'll pay attention to this for future circuits ! You mentionned this part is deprecated ,can you advise me an RRIO opamp to play with ? (I'm trying to amplify a 162KHz signal received by a tuned ferite rod)

Comment: why would you need the full 0 to 5V input range for that? Just bias your input to say 2.5 V?

Comment: Ok I see I can keep the TS972 for experimenting by working around VCC/2, to respect  VDD + 1.15 to VCC - 1.15 V range.

Comment: exactly! Just use a rather high-ohmic voltage dividers (maybe 2× 1 MΩ) to put your antenna-originating signal up to 2.5 V (voltage divider: VCC-1MΩ-(x)-1MΩ-GND, couple in the antenna via a capacitor to (x), connect your non-inverting opamp input to (x).